# End javaw.exe process softly with taskkill

Tags: java, shutdown, taskkill, javaw

I encountered a problem closing my javaw.exe process.
I like to do it in a soft way, so taskkill /F won't help.

Trying to close the javaw by taskkill /PID  will end up in an "SUCESS" message, but the process still keeps running.

I'm using Windows XP SP 3 and got administrator rights on this machine.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally I found a solution for my problem, but is not solved using taskkill. There is a program written to send a CTRL-BREAK to any process called "SendSignal". I had tried this before, but all my process was responding had been an error-message and it kept running. I changed this program sending CTRL+C. After this I was able to shut my Javaw process gently. Thanks to all, for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
taskkill /im javaw.exe
```

Comment: Thank you for your posting.

taskkill with /im has the same effect like /pid. So still same problem.